# I want to use "awk" or sed to print all the lines that start with "comm=" in a file

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I want to use "awk" or "sed" to print all the lines that start with `comm=` from the file `filex`, Note that each line contains "comm=somthing"

```
for example : comm=rm , comm=ll, comm=ls  ....
```

How can i achieve that ?

Comment: How is made your file ? one `comm=rm` per line ?

Comment: yes per line, each line contains comm=x

Answer (score 26):

For lines that start with `comm=`

```
sed -n '/^comm=/p' filex

awk '/^comm=/' filex
```

If `comm=` is anywhere in the line then

```
sed -n '/comm=/p' filex

awk '/comm=/' filex
```

Comment: that only works it comm is at the beginning of the line, how to make it work if comm is at any place in each line, thanks for ur help Jaypa

Comment: this is returning the whole line i just want to return the match, and this is how it can be done : grep -o '\<comm=[[:alnum:]]*\>' , thanks for your help

Comment: For brevity you might like `sed '/\<comm=/!d'`

Answer (score 6):

You could use [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) also :

```
grep comm= filex
```

this will display all the lines containing `comm=`.

Comment: or `grep "^comm=" filex` to match lines starting with `comm=` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using grep:

```
grep -o '\<comm=[[:alnum:]]*\>'
```

This treats a word as consisting of alphanumeric characters; extend the character class as needed.

Comment: @bob Given that you've stated in a comment that it's just one `comm=` per line, this solution is overkill; use the answer from Cédric Julien. Additionally, to say "thanks" on Stackoverflow, you can just upvote the useful answers rather than commenting.

Answer (score 0):

If `grep` is ok to use, you could give a try to:

```
grep -E "^comm=" file
```